# Which preposition for '___ the exclusion'?

Tags: grammaticality, difference

> Second, the consumers with most money have the greatest pull in the market. As a
>   result, resources may be devoted to producing luxuries for the rich **to** the exclusion of
>   necessities for the poor. While this is really brought about by the unequal distribution
>   of wealth and income rather than by the market system, the fact is that the latter tends
>   to produce, and even to increase, such inequality.

Why isn't **at** used, or some other preposition? What are the similarities and differences?

Source: p 118, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Comment: I think the _to_ could be changed to _at_ and the sentence's meaning would stay the same. There are some cases where more than one preposition can be used; I think you've found one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**to the exclusion of someone or something** is a set phrase; an idiom, if you will. It's always used with *to*. Check out this dictionary entry: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to-the-exclusion-of

Comment: http://definitions.uslegal.com/j/judicial-exclusion/ shows _at the exlusion_ being used as well...

Comment: "at" is called for in another similar set phrase: _at the expense of_    . . .  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/at-the-expense-of?q=at+the+expense+of